# Error Installing GLFW-b on OS X

Tags: macos, haskell, osx-mavericks, glfw, cabal-install

So I'm trying to install [Lamdu](http://peaker.github.io/lamdu/), and because it relies on GLFW (`brew install glfw3`)I've had to install that, and the GLFW bindings for Haskell.  I cloned the Lamdu repository, `cd lamdu`, `cabal configure`, and the only dependencies that it says I don't have are GLFW-b.  `cabal install glfw-b` gets the same error, every time (I've tried reinstalling the Haskell Platform with a binary and rebuilding from source, nothing changed)

What I think are the most important lines of the error:

`3.0.3.2.o: unknown symbol '__objc_empty_vtable'
ghc: unable to load package 'bindings-GLFW-3.0.3.2'`

You can find the full error [here](http://pastebin.com/La9k8zYb)

Comment: I've since switched to Arch Linux, and that has solved the problem

Comment: Supposedly, this issue is solved in GHC 7.8, which is part of the latest version of the Haskell Platform: https://github.com/bsl/bindings-GLFW/issues/8